# Tuple vs Generator expression. Why does performance flip, the longer the sequence gets?

Tags: python, performance, tuples, generator

I was looking at the following code and thought I noticed a potential performance issue.

```
def multiply(x):
    return x * 10

def test():
    data = tuple(x for x in range(5))

    first_map = tuple(map(
        multiply,
        tuple(x for x in data)
    ))
    second_map = tuple(map(
        multiply,
        tuple(x for x in data)
    ))

    ziped = tuple(zip(data, second_map, first_map))
    return ziped

import timeit
print(timeit.timeit('test()', globals=globals()))
```

Running this prints `5.317162958992412` for me.

I thought all these intermediate `tuple` would cause multiple iterations over data and so I turned it into the following.

```
def multiply(x):
    return x * 10

def test():
    data = tuple(x for x in range(5))

    first_map = map(
        multiply,
        (x for x in data)
    )
    second_map = map(
        multiply,
        (x for x in data)
    )

    ziped = tuple(zip(data, second_map, first_map))
    return ziped

import timeit
print(timeit.timeit('test()', globals=globals()))
```

And in fact, running this prints `4.783027238998329` for me, so we've optimized the performance. Yay!

**But now comes the suprising (to me) part!**. As we scale up the data, the results flip!

In other words, if we change `data` to be `data = tuple(x for x in range(50))`, then, the version with the intermediate tuples becomes the faster one.

What am I missing?

Comment: you haven't convinced me the timing is meaningfully different

Comment: I have tested both of your functions with 10 million elements and the second one is consistently faster.

Comment: I think the tuple conversion in the first version, adds a slight overhead.

Comment: I have also checked this with jupyter notebook timeit, with 7 runs of 10000 loops, and the results are not flipping, even at 50, the generator version is faster. Same as for @jdehesa.

Comment: @Chris_Rands the real code is doing some normalization on streaming data so instead of numbers, we have some bigger structured data, and instead of `multiply` we execute some cryptographic functions. Other than that, the structure is pretty much the same and optimizations in this code have a high impact.

Comment: @jdehesa  Mmh..This is weird. It consistently behaves the other way on my machine. Don't know what to make of this.